# Как сделать так ,чтобы окно было прозрачным, а виджет — нет tkinter?

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, mac, виджет

При запуске следующего кода

```
try:
    from Tkinter import*
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
button=Button(root,text='example')
button.pack()
root.wm_attributes('-alpha',0.5)
root.mainloop()
```

Помимо самого окна кнопка тоже становится прозрачной(на половину).Как сделать так ,чтобы окно было прозрачным, а виджет — нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Важно помнить, что tkinter плохо приспособлен к кроссплатформенности.

**Windows 8.1**:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.lift()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
root.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")

root.geometry("+250+250")

button=Button(root, text='example')
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**macOS**:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
root.wm_attributes("-transparent", True)
root.config(bg='systemTransparent')

root.geometry("+250+250")

button = tk.Button(root, text='example')
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```